# Proving the existence of a diffeomorphism with no fixed points

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

Problem: let M be a compact connected manifold, and let $f \colon M \to M$ be a local diffeomorphism with degree two. Prove that if $f$ has one fixed point, then there exists a diffeomorphism $g \colon M \to M$ that has no fixed points.

I'm not really sure how to begin the problem, any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Since $f$ is a degree $2$ covering map, we see that $\chi(M) = 0$. By a nontrivial result, this means there's a vector field $X$ on $M$ with no zeroes. Let $g$ be the time-$\varepsilon$ flow of $X$.

However, it bothers me that the hypothesis we were given that $f$ has one fixed point seems irrelevant.

Comment: The statement of the problem is indeed somewhat odd. Your proof shows that if M has a local diffeomorphism of any degree $>1$ then $M$ has a diffeomorphism with no fixed points.

Comment: Here's another approach that seems to work: $f : M \to M$ is a 2-fold covering map, so is in particular a normal cover. Then there is a nontrivial deck transformation of $f$ which flips every 2-tuple of fibers of $f$. Call this $h : M \to M$. This is a self-homeomorphism with no fixed points, and modulo some argument should be a diffeomorphism as well, since $f$ was a smooth cover.

Comment: To summarize, what Ted's argument shows that you can moreover pick your fixed-point free diffeomorphism to be homotopic to the identity (because it's a flow of a vector field). My argument shows that total space of any double cover whatsoever admits a fixed point free self-homeomorphism, I think.